# Not able to Explode and select in the same expression in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here is my schema

```
root
 |-- DataPartition: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TimeStamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TRFCoraxData_instrumentId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- TRFCoraxData_organizationId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Dividends: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- cr:AnnouncementDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cr:CorporateActionAdjustedDividendGrossAmount: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cr:CorporateActionAdjustedDividendNetAmount: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cr:CurrencyId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cr:DividendEventId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cr:DividendGrossAmount: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cr:DividendNetAmount: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cr:DividendType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cr:ExDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cr:PayDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cr:PeriodDuration: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cr:PeriodEndDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cr:RecordDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FFAction|!|: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to explode and select all columns in the same expression so that 
I need not have to write with Column or Select by giving the column name separately .

Here is my code where i am exploding

```
 val temp2 = temp1.select(getDataPartition($"DataPartition").as("DataPartition"), $"TimeStamp".as("TimeStamp"), $"TRFCoraxData_instrumentId".as("TRFCoraxData_instrumentId"), $"TRFCoraxData_organizationId".as("TRFCoraxData_organizationId"),explode($"Dividends"), $"FFAction|!|".as("FFAction|!|"))
 val temp = temp2.select(temp2.columns.map(x => col(x).as(x.replace("cr:", ""))): _*)

temp.show(false)
```

And here is my output that i am getting where i am getting explode column as Col .

How can i get the coloumn name also in the same expression

```
+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|DataPartition    |TimeStamp                |TRFCoraxData_instrumentId|TRFCoraxData_organizationId|col                                                                                                                                                                                    |FFAction|!||
+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|ThirdPartyPrivate|2017-06-07T09:18:33+00:00|8590925624               |4296241518                 |[2009-07-14T00:00:00+00:00,null,0.35,500110,73014469387,0.35,null,INTE,2009-08-13T00:00:00+00:00,2009-09-15T00:00:00+00:00,P3M,2009-09-30T00:00:00+00:00,2009-08-17T00:00:00+00:00]    |O|!|       |
|ThirdPartyPrivate|2017-06-07T09:18:33+00:00|8590925624               |4296241518                 |[2008-02-05T00:00:00+00:00,null,0.3,500110,73015860528,0.3,null,INTE,2008-02-14T00:00:00+00:00,2008-03-17T00:00:00+00:00,P3M,2008-03-31T00:00:00+00:00,2008-02-19T00:00:00+00:00]      |O|!|       |
|ThirdPartyPrivate|2017-06-07T09:18:33+00:00|8590925624               |4296241518                 |[2008-04-29T00:00:00+00:00,null,0.3,500110,73015864496,0.3,null,INTE,2008-05-14T00:00:00+00:00,2008-06-16T00:00:00+00:00,P3M,2008-06-30T00:00:00+00:00,2008-05-16T00:00:00+00:00]      |O|!|       |
+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i get the coloumn name also in the same expression

`col` is the column name given by spark itself for the exploded column. You can use *alias* as you have done for other columns if you want some other names other than `col` as

```
explode($"Dividends").as("Dividends")
```

and then you can *expand the struct column into separate columns using `.*`* as

```
temp2.select(col("Dividends.*"))
```

> I want to explode and select all columns in the same expression so that I need not have to write with Column or Select by giving the column name separately

Only one generator can be used with one expression.

Comment: Thanks so this was the catch Only one generators can be used with one expression.